# Using Livewire and getting message that AlpineJS has already been loaded

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-jetstream

I've recently started a new Jetstream project with Livewire. I've been playing around with setting up my base layout etc and I keep getting a message in the console (which I'm not sure if its mucking up what I'm trying to do with Alpine). In the console it says:

```
Livewire: It looks like AlpineJS has already been loaded. Make sure Livewire's scripts are loaded before Alpine
```

Which is confusing me as I am not loading AlpineJS anywhere else. I don't have any CDN references anywhere in my base templates. Alpine is only referenced once where it gets set up which was automatically generated when I first created the jetstream project (under resources/js/app.js).

My understanding is that Livewire already loads Alpine automatically. So why would this error come up?

Comment: maybe this can help you https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js. If you have installed Alpine as a module, consider v2 has start seperatly `Alpine.start()`. Check out the [AlpineJS installation guide](https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/installation)

Answer (score 2):

If you installed alpine as a module and you are having this error, go to your layout file (app.blade.php) or whatever full livewire page that's giving this error or where you imported your livewire scripts and app.js file, then import your livewire scripts before app.js e.g

```
@livewireScripts
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

instead of the old way:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@livewireScripts
```

Comment: Having the same issue - your suggestions does not solve it unfortunately.